# creating a data frame from several JSON file on Python

Tags: python, json, loops

I have to create a data frame from a series of JSON files.  This is what I have so far with some context

```
#Importing helper libraries
import sys
import json


from helpers.helper_functions import execute_bigquery

#importing standard libraries
import requests

#get data from bigquery
authors_df = execute_bigquery(f"""
    SELECT author
    FROM `XXX`
    LIMIT 1000
    """)

#for each row
for index, row in authors_df.iterrows():
    #get the author
    author = row['author']
```

Basically author is a list of 1,000 IDs I want to collect data from (for example `1232`, `456093`, `273`, etc.).

The information I want for these authors can be obtained from a link that changes depending on the author

```
    #build the url
    url = f'http://keystone-db.default.svc.cluster.local:5000/keystonedb/profiles/resonance/categorization?profileId={author}&regionId=1'    

    #get the json value
    json_value = requests.get(url).json()

    #display it
    print(json.dumps(json_value['resonanceCategorizations']['1']['fullData'], indent=2))
```

Here is part of the output for the first 2 authors `"45866207"` and `"54502344"`):

```
45866207
[
  {
    "seed": 24868793,
    "globalSegmentId": 26895,
    "globalSegmentName": "Luxury Accessories & Jewellery",
    "regionId": 15,
    "resonance": 0.8028571009635925,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 76611584,
    "globalSegmentId": 17899,
    "globalSegmentName": "Jewellery",
    "regionId": 15,
    "resonance": 0.8028001189231873,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 40893487,
    "globalSegmentId": 17899,
    "globalSegmentName": "Jewellery",
    "regionId": 15,
    "resonance": 0.7982199192047119,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 74701069,
    "globalSegmentId": 17912,
    "globalSegmentName": "Heritage Designer Brands",
    "regionId": 15,
    "resonance": 0.6809910535812378,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 936905156,
    "globalSegmentId": 17899,
    "globalSegmentName": "Jewellery",
    "regionId": 15,
    "resonance": 0.6566575169563293,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 14831515,
    "globalSegmentId": 17801,
    "globalSegmentName": "Mining & Resources",
    "regionId": 1,
    "resonance": 0.6080579161643982,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 36544806,
    "globalSegmentId": 18392,
    "globalSegmentName": "Rugby",
    "regionId": 12,
    "resonance": 0.5898635983467102,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 26494583,
    "globalSegmentId": 26895,
    "globalSegmentName": "Luxury Accessories & Jewellery",
    "regionId": 15,
    "resonance": 0.5888025760650635,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1


    }
    ]
54502344
[
  {
    "seed": 255420441,
    "globalSegmentId": 18187,
    "globalSegmentName": "Luxury Cars",
    "regionId": 18,
    "resonance": 0.9264420866966248,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  {
    "seed": 2650413864,
    "globalSegmentId": 18187,
    "globalSegmentName": "Luxury Cars",
    "regionId": 18,
    "resonance": 0.9237868189811707,
    "isGlobal": true,
    "globalRegion": 1
  },
  ...
```

and same for any other author in the list.

What I want to obtain is a way to extract for each author variables in the first element of the JSON list, all the variables in the second element of the list and all the ones in the third element and put them in a dataset with 1,000 rows (one for each author).

This is the output I want (1,000 rows corresponding to 1,000 authors and 21 variables: 7 variables or "keys" for each of the first 3 elements in the list):

```
     Author     seed_1     GlobalSegmentId_1 ... seed_2     GlobalSegmentId_2 .... seed_3 ... globalregion_3      
     45866207  24868793    26895                 76611584     17899    .....
     54502344  255420441    ....   .....
      ....    ....
```

Comment: I’m confused. What is the issue, exactly? What is that first snippet doing, with the `iterrows()`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the first chance of text allow me to get a list of "author IDs" that I would need to input one by one in the "url" and get the corresponding "JSON" file. I printed the a few lines of what I obtained so far (i.e. A series of son files for each authorID, one by one) at this point what I want is to extract information from the JSON files, and create a  dataset where each row  contains the information corresponding to that author. (first raw , author 1 and information from its Json file. Second raws author 2 and info from its Json file and so on) hope it is clear